# Could I have an event listener on Download button from a Tableau Crosstab (Javascript API)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, iframe, tableau-api

I actived the component on a Tableau Vizview called crosstab, I want to know if is possible get a event listener or get the event and trigger a JavaScript action. This is how shows in the vizview:

[image]

This is my current code to handle this

```
   exportVizData: function(viz) {
        viz.showExportCrossTabDialog();
    },
```

This is the API reference
[Tableau JavaScript API](http://examples.tabcmd.com/JSAPI_Examples.html)

In my first impression I think is not possible because is an iframe, and this iframe comes from a different server that my page host.

Comment: You can listen for events. Check out the tutorial http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/samples/en-us/js_api/tutorial.htm

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question: You want to trigger the download (without showing the tableau download dialogue) to cross-tab for a particular view using your own java script.

You can achieve the same result by hitting the URL for the view and appending a format parameter in the end.
For example if your view URL is:

```
https://www.mytableauserver.com/t/mySite/views/myWorkbook/myView
```

Then you should hit

```
https://www.mytableauserver.com/t/mySite/views/myWorkbook/myView?&:format=CSV
```

This works for PDF and PNG formats too.